# How can I change database name in Sql Server with code?

Tags: database

I want to change database name from Test to NewTest

```
Alter Database Test Set NewTest
```

But it does not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
ALTER DATABASE Test MODIFY NAME = NewTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the account you are using has the correct privileges.